# Put a character by according to a list of its index number to a string [Python 2.7]

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, indexing, character

The sample string and the given range of index numbers of a character can be seen below:

```
a_str = 'Iamgoingtoschool'
num_index = ['1','3','8','10','16',...]
```

As the position of a character (`'|'`) should be assigned as index number of the list(`num_index`), the outcome should be like this:

```
get_result = 'I|am|going|to|school|'
```

The attempt is in below:

```
for i in num_index:
    get_res = a_str[:i]+'|'+a_str[i:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your values in `num_index` should **not** be strings. They should be integers.

```
num_index = [int(n) for n in num_index]
```

After that, you're completely overwriting `get_result` on each iteration of your loop. Instead, strive for something more like this:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

get_result = a_str[:num_index[0]]  # Start with the first chunk of `a_str`
for a, b in pairwise(num_index):
    get_result += '|' + a_str[a:b]
get_result += '|' + a_str[num_index[-1]:]  # Attach the last part.
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do --

```
    a_str = 'Iamgoingtoschool'
    num_index = ['1','3','8','10','14','16']

    num_index = map(int,num_index)
    a_len = len(a_str)
    num_index_len = len(num_index)
    i=0
    total_len = a_len+num_index_len
    res = []
    current_num_index = 0

    while i<=a_len and i<total_len and current_num_index<num_index_len:

         if i<=a_len and i<num_index[current_num_index]:
             res.append(a_str[i])
             i += 1

    else:
         res.append('|')
         current_num_index+=1

    while i<a_len and i<total_len:
        res.append(a_str[i])
        i+=1

    print(''.join(res))
```